# Interpreting the Cross Section Ratio $R$

Tags: particle-physics, standard-model, feynman-diagrams, scattering-cross-section, electroweak

Below is experimental data for the ratio $$R=\frac{\sigma(e^+e^-\rightarrow hadrons)}{\sigma(e^+e^-\rightarrow\mu^+\mu^-)}$$ as a function of the centre of mass energy $\sqrt s$.[image]

I am interested in the peak at around $100GeV$ which corresponds to the resonance of the $Z^0$ boson. There are two ways of looking at this that I have in mind:

1. We can effectively ignore the electromagnetic process around this energy, and so each process should have it's own Breit-Wigner peak centred on the mass energy of the $Z^0$. The ratio of these is just a constant.
2. Thinking in terms of Feynman rules and again ignoring the electromagnetic process around this region, each process has the same propagator and vertex factors (roughly - ignore quark mixing) and there are some extra factors due to different quarks being possible and colour degeneracy, but still the ratio should be a constant (one possible issue here is interference between Feynman diagrams which I have neglected?).

So my question is why does the peak exist in the data?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> [The figure shown in the OP question above ...] is experimental data for the ratio $R = $ [...] as a function of the centre of mass energy $\sqrt{s}$

The so called [cross section ratio](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/R_(cross_section_ratio)) $$R[~\sqrt{s}~] = \frac{\sigma^{(0)}[~e^+~e^- \rightarrow \text{hadrons}, \sqrt{s}~]}{\sigma^{(0)}[~e^+~e^- \rightarrow \mu^+~\mu^-, \sqrt{s}~]}$$
??

Actually, surprisingly, No!;
that's not (quite) what's shown there; and therein lies the answer to your question.

Rather, as the [caption of PDG Figure 44.6](http://pdg.lbl.gov/2012/hadronic-xsections/rpp2012-sigma_R_ee_plots.pdf) explains (and surely the [PDG](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Particle_Data_Group) is the authoritative source) the figure shows instead the ratio of the experimentally determined hadronic cross section (incl. suitable corrections), $$\sigma^{(0)}[~e^+~e^- \rightarrow \text{hadrons},\sqrt{s}~]$$
and a "normalization denominator" $$ \frac{4}{3}~\pi~\alpha^2[~s~] ~/~ s,$$
where apparently [$\alpha[~s~]$ expresses electromagnetic coupling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coupling_constant#QED_and_the_Landau_pole) **only**, i.e. without accounting for weak coupling which is experimentally dominant at center-of-mass energy near the nominal mass of the $Z^0$ boson.

Consequently, while the arguments laid out in the OP seem quite compelling to me, they don't address what's actually presented in the figure, including the obvious "$Z^0$ peak".
(I consider the OP question quite astute nevertheless, +1; and I even hope that it might lead the PDG to reconsider the labelling of its Figure 44.6.)