# Why is the $Z$ resonance cross section so much larger for hadrons?

Tags: particle-physics, standard-model, feynman-diagrams, scattering-cross-section, electroweak

[image]

The image shows experimental data for the ratio of cross sections $$R=\frac{\sigma(e^+e^-\rightarrow\text{hadrons})}{\sigma(e^+e^-\rightarrow\mu^+\mu^-)}.$$
I am wondering why $R$ is so large for the $Z$ resonance. I thought that it would only depend on the branching ratios of the $Z$ decay into hadrons and muons, but this gives $R\approx 20$ which is much too small.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Interpreting the Cross Section Ratio R](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/249340/)

Comment: Read the figure caption 5 times!   This R, as normalized, *excludes* Z->μμ decays, including only a theoretical QED normalization, instead! The PDG perpetrators have been highly unfriendly.